# Performing range filters on aggregated field (e.g. Avg of score) in Elastic Search

Tags: java, postgresql, elasticsearch

I am using latest Elastic Search Version 1.3.2.
I just want to perform range filter on an aggregated field (e.g. Average of students score). I am using the following query ..

```
   {
          "query": {
            "bool": {
              "must": [
                { "match": { "districtCode": "99322760000000" } },
                { "match": { "testWindowCode": "CA-SBAC-SBAC Summative" }},
                { "match": { "subject": "English" }},
                { "match": { "grade": 6 }}
              ]
            }
            },  "aggs": {
            "group_by_school": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "schoolCode"
              },
            "aggs": {
                    "average_scale_score": {
                      "avg": {
                        "field": "scaleScore"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
     }
```

This query providing me the aggregation result like buckets of schools and their avg scale score which is correct. Now I want filter those school whose avg scale scores are falling between some specified range. I searched through internet but could not able to get on how to apply range filter on aggregated filed (e.g. is this case avg scale score). can someone please help.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible on the current version of ElasticSearch (1.4.2).

However, this feature is [detailed in Github](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/issues/8110) and should be included in the 2.0 version.